# Subsetting by row condition in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm trying to work out a way of subsetting a matrix which is purely numeric (i.e. no column/row names). To put this in the form of a worked example, I would like to drop rows that do not meet a logical condition.

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(sample.int(100, 10*10, TRUE), 10, 10)
```

Say I want to make a subset so I keep rows where the maximum row value is 90 or over, but drop those which do not meet this condition.

The only way I can think of doing this is through an if/else loop (`max(m[i,]) > 90`) but I feel there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `any` here is another option `m[apply(m , 1, function(x) any(!x < 90)),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in several steps.

First, find the maxima of the rows using [`apply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) over the rows:

```
maxima = apply(m, 1, max)
# [1] 92 99 99 98 93 96 98 91 98 84
```

Next, get those that are greater than your threshold:

```
above = maxima >= 90
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, use this to subset your data:

```
m[above, ]
```

Or, in one line:

```
m[apply(m, 1, max) >= 90, ]
```

You can expand the condition arbitrarily. For instance, to test whether the maximum is *between* two values, you can do this:

```
between = function (x, lower, upper)
    x >= lower & x <= upper

m[between(apply(m, 1, max), 90, 97), ]
```

Comment: Great thanks for this. I've always struggled getting on with apply. If I wanted to use two conditions (e.g. greater than 90 and less than 97) to have a range of maxima, how that fit with the apply function?

Comment: @jordanawhite See updated answer (last paragraph). Notably, it’s independent of the `apply` function call; what we replace is the comparison logic (`. >= 90` vs something else).

Comment: Brilliant, just applied it to my actual data and it works perfectly. Thanks, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 6):

You can simply create a logical matrix using `m >= 90`. That is possible because `>` is generic function with a `matrix` method (see `?S4groupGeneric` for other functions with similar behaviour). Then, we can just run `rowSums` over it and check that the condition applies, for example

```
m[rowSums(m >= 90) > 0, ]
```

That means that if *any* value is equal or higher than 90, for sure the maximum is higher too- so no need to look for the maximum in the first place.

---

An alternative option is to use the very efficient `matrixStats` package and its `rowMaxs` function

```
library(matrixStats)
m[rowMaxs(m) >= 90, ]
```

---

As per your comments, here a possible vectorized range solution

```
Maxima <- rowMaxs(m)
m[Maxima >= 90 & Maxima <= 97, ]
```

Comment: @jordanawhite, Although you completely ignored this answer, see edit regarding your comments.

Comment: Thanks for this David. I followed up on the first reply, but thank you for your answer I shall look in to the matrixStats package as I'm sure it will be useful for other work I'm doing